# datadirectory incorrect in nested application

Tags: asp.net

I have used the |DataDirectory| value in a connection string in web.config. It works fine on my local machine.

However it fails when the site is uploaded. The uploaded version of my site is a sub-directory / sub-application of another site. The |datadirectory| value does not reference my App_Data folder, but a folder on the hosting computer.

Is there a way around this? I want to avoid having 2 different web.config files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that SQL Express is supported at your host? If not ask their support team. It could also be that you need to attach your .mdf file, after uploading it to the server, to a full blown SQL Server. Again ask your hosting company. Also you should receive from them the correct connectionstring. Also find out more about [Connection strings](http://connectionstrings.com/).

Grz, Kris.